# How to write proofs for universal composable security？

Tags: universal-composability

Recently, I learn Ran Canetti's famous paper, *"Universally Composable Security: A New Paradigm for Cryptographic Protocols"*. But I find it very difficult to grasp. When I read the paper that proves the security of the protocols in the UC-framework, I can understand it a little bit, but I still cannot write the proof myself.

I have read some answers on this website, including

- [Simulation-based proofs and universal composability proofs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30703/simulation-based-proofs-and-universal-composability-proofs),
- [What is universal composability guaranteeing, specifically? Where does it apply, and where does it not?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/85739/what-is-universal-composability-guaranteeing-specifically-where-does-it-apply/85763#85763),

but they just teach me what is UC-framework, while I am still confused on how to write the proof(how to define the ideal functionality, etc.) after I read them. So is there any other good way to learn to write the proof in UC-framework?

Comment: Have you looked at [How to Simulate It](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf) by our very own Yehuda Lindell?

Comment: yes, but it just focuses on stand-alone model, just for sequential composition. Not the same as UC, which is for concurrent composition