# Expanding stand-alone simulation-based proofs to UC proofs

Tags: provable-security, universal-composability, simulation

This is a follow-up question to [Mikero](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/192/mikero)’s answer to [Simulation-based proofs and universal composability proofs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30703/simulation-based-proofs-and-universal-composability-proofs).

Let there be some protocol $\pi$ running between two parties $A$ and $B$.
Furthermore, assume that I have proven $\pi$ secure using a [stand-alone simulation-based proof](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf). That is, I have written some proof $\mathsf{P}$, constructing a simulator for $A$ (and later for $B$) in the ideal world that interfaces with adversary $\mathcal{A}$ in a real-world execution of $\pi$ where it pretends to be $B$.

This results in sequential composability. Now, I would additionally like to prove security under parallel composition, but avoid the increased complexity of a full UC proof.

I understand that one can assume adversary $\mathcal{A}$ to be a *dummy* adversary (see the answer in that previous question, a combination with the external environment). If the simulators in my proof $\mathsf{P}$ do not make use of *rewinding* arguments and instead run and interfere with $\mathcal{A}$ straightline, is this a valid argument to show security under parallel composition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question (surprisingly) depends on whether the protocol is *perfectly* secure or not. I refer you to the following paper.

> [Information-Theoretically Secure Protocols and Security Under Composition](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/630.pdf) by Kushilevitz, Lindell, Rabin.

They prove the following (theorem statements copy/pasted from their intro):

- There exist protocols that are **statistically secure** in the stand-alone information theoretical model and are proven secure using straight-line black-box simulation, and yet are not secure under concurrent general composition.
- Every protocol that is **perfectly secure** in the stand-alone model, and has a straight-line black-box simulator, is secure under concurrent general composition.

That being said, this result seems to heavily rely on specifics and edge cases of the standard security definitions. I would say that the spirit of your suggestion (straight-line, black-box, standalone implies UC) is very reasonable and applies in all reasonable situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very interesting!

Comment: Theorem 5 of the [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/630.pdf) you point to mentions a very reasonable requirement. _start synchronization_ is sufficient as a formal argument for security under parallel composition.