# Do simulator based proofs still rely on the random oracle model?

Tags: provable-security

I have seen many game based proofs using the random oracle model (ROM), do simulator based proofs require it? Is it possible to do a simulator based proof for every game based proof?

For context: [What are the differences between proofs based on simulation and proofs based on games?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/what-are-the-differences-between-proofs-based-on-simulation-and-proofs-based-on)

Comment: I guess it's Random Oracle Model

Comment: @Conrado Thanks, that made more sense than it should :P Deleting the comments after editing the question. The author can edit the question if that's not what was meant with "ROM".

Comment: Game _vs._ simulator and ROM _vs._ no-ROM (‘standard model’, for those who turn their noses up at ROM) are independent properties.